# Pattern in prolog

Tags: prolog, cycle

Take all the distinct bit patterns of length N and arrange them in a cycle such that each
pattern overlaps with its two neighbours in N - 1 bits. Then 
flatten the cycle into a Prolog list.

Write a predicate `pattern(N,L)` that returns a list of bits that comprises all the bit
patterns of length N > 0 following the above rules. Note, there are multiple possible
solutions. You need only produce one.

```
?- pattern(1, L).
L = [0,1]
?- pattern(2, L).
L = [0,0,1,1]
?- pattern(3, L).
L = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]
```

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. What did you already do, where are you stuck, what are your questions?

Comment: Aren't called [De Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence)? Are you having problems generating the cycle or in flattening it into a list?

Answer (score 2):

A neat method for generating these is given in [A Simple Combinatorial Algorithm for De Bruijn Sequences](http://duch.mimuw.edu.pl/~rytter/TEACHING/TEKSTY/PreferOpposite.pdf) by Abbas Alkahim.

It's probably suitable for Prolog implementation with minor adaptation.  Calling his method the Prefer Opposite Algorithm, the steps outlined are as follows for pattern length N:

1. Set first N "bits" of list to 0.
2. For the next "bit" consider one of *opposite* parity to the one immediately preceding.
3. If the resulting N bit pattern did not exist previously in the list, then adjoin that bit to the end of the list and proceed. (back to step 2)
4. On the other hand if that pattern did already exist, try a next bit of parity *equal* to the one preceding.
5. If that N bit pattern did not already exist, then adjoin that bit to the end of the list and proceed. (back to step 2).
6. Otherwise stop.

This results in a sequence that contains all the binary patterns of length N, *except* the pattern of N 1's, and terminates with a pattern of N-1 1's followed by N-1 0's.  To obtain a full De Bruijn sequence, replace those final N-1 0's with a single 1 entry (and the sequence should wrap around to a cycle of length 2^N at that point).

For a Prolog implementation I suspect things would proceed most easily if bits are added to the beginning of the list, rather than to the end.  Anyway I'll give it a try and let you know if it works as nicely as I hope it will.

---

I wrote my code last evening and tested it this morning, trying the opposite parity bit first and adding bits to the beginning of the list.  The case N = 1 looked like it was going to be a little anomalous, and after an effort to code that in common with N > 1, I went back to just returning [1,0] for N = 1.

Another good exercise would be to write the code adding bits to the end of the sequence using [difference list](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/lp/lectures/11-diff.pdf) techniques.

---

**Added: (the code)**

Here's an implementation that builds the list representing a De Bruijn sequence by adding entries to the front of a list, deterministic predicate **binaryDeBruijnSeq/2** taking a (bound) positive integer N for pattern length and returning said list as second argument:

```
/*
   Prolog implementation of PreferOpposite
     "A Simple Combinatorial Algorithm
          for De Bruijn Sequences"
             by Abbas Alkahim:
   http://duch.mimuw.edu.pl/~rytter/TEACHING/TEKSTY/PreferOpposite.pdf

   Construct binary De Bruijn sequence for all N bit patterns
   (a list construed as cycle) by adding to front of list:

    1.  If N = 1, return [1,0]; otherwise begin the sequence
        with N zeros.
    2.  For next bit, first try one of parity opposite to the
        previous one, then try one of the same parity, so that
        an N bit pattern not already found results.  Repeat.
    3.  When no further bits can be added, the final N-1 bits
        will be zeros.  Replace them with a single one bit.
*/
binaryDeBruijnSeq(1,[1,0]).
binaryDeBruijnSeq(N,[1|ZeroStrip]) :-
    N > 1,
    zeroNFill(N,ZeroNBits),
    accrueDeBruijn(ZeroNBits,ZeroNBits,Accrue),
    zeroStrip(Accrue,ZeroStrip).

zeroNFill(0,[ ]).
zeroNFill(N,[0|Fill]) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N-1,
    zeroNFill(M,Fill).

accrueDeBruijn(NBits,SoFar,Final) :-
    NBits = [Bit|_],
    shorten(NBits,Short),
    Opp is 1 - Bit,
    not(alreadyFound([Opp|Short],SoFar)),
    !,
    accrueDeBruijn([Opp|Short],[Opp|SoFar],Final).
accrueDeBruijn(NBits,SoFar,Final) :-
    NBits = [Bit|_],
    shorten(NBits,Short),
    not(alreadyFound([Bit|Short],SoFar)),
    !,
    accrueDeBruijn([Bit|Short],[Bit|SoFar],Final).
accrueDeBruijn(_,Final,Final).

shorten([_],[ ]) :- !.
shorten([H|T],[H|S]) :- shorten(T,S).

/* alreadyFound(NBits,DeBruijn) */
alreadyFound(NBits,DeBruijn) :-
    initialSeq(NBits,DeBruijn).
alreadyFound(NBits,[_|DeBruijn]) :-
    alreadyFound(NBits,DeBruijn).

initialSeq([ ],_).
initialSeq([H|T],[H|L]) :-
    initialSeq(T,L).

zeroStrip([0|T],S) :- !, zeroStrip(T,S).
zeroStrip(S,S).
```

Here's also the code for my follow-up exercise, **pattern/2** that builds the list by adding to the tail.  Even accounting for the fact that predicate **initialSeq/2** is reused from the above, the resulting implementation is slightly more compact:

```
/* follow-up, build De Bruijn sequence by adding to tail */
pattern(1,[0,1]).
pattern(N,DeBruijn) :-
    N > 1,
    zeroNFront(N,[1|X],DeBruijn),
    DeBruijn = [0|NBits],
    patternAux(N,DeBruijn,NBits,[1|X],1),
    !.

zeroNFront(0,Last,Last).
zeroNFront(N,List,Last) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N-1,
    zeroNFront(M,[0|List],Last).

patternAux(N,DeBruijn,_,[1,1],C) :-
    C is N-1,
    !.
patternAux(N,DeBruijn,NBits,[Bit|X],C) :-
    Opp is 1-Bit,
    X = [Opp|Y],
    NBits = [_|MBits],
    not(alreadyFoundAux(DeBruijn,MBits,Y)),
    patternAux(N,DeBruijn,MBits,[Opp|Y],Opp).
patternAux(N,DeBruijn,NBits,[Bit|X],C) :-
    X = [Bit|Y],
    NBits = [_|MBits],
    ( Bit = 1 -> D is C+1 ; D = 0 ),
    patternAux(N,DeBruijn,MBits,[Bit|Y],D).

alreadyFoundAux(L,L,[ ]) :- !, fail.
alreadyFoundAux(K,L,[ ]) :-
    initialSeq(L,K).
alreadyFoundAux([_|K],L,Y) :-
    alreadyFoundAux(K,L,Y).
```

Note:  For the same N the result of **binaryDeBruijnSeq/2** will be the reversed list of **pattern/2**.